# RESTful POST to fetch token thru node.js from RESTful server

Tags: rest

I am trying to create .js code to fetch token from RESTFul server using username/password

```
/////////////

   const https = require('https');
   const request = require('request');
   var querystring = require('querystring');





    var options ={
      host: '10.41.74.70',
      path: '/tron/api/v1/tokens',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {

            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

        },
        data: {
        'username': "admin",
        'password': "adminpw",
        'tenant': "master"
   }
   };
   process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
   var req = https.request(options, function(res){
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });


   res.on('end', function(){
    var price = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(price);
   })
   });





   req.end();
   /////////////////
```

I want to fetch token from RESTful Server thru node.js using above call.

I am getting error:

```
 mgoyal@MDW-MGOYAL-02 MINGW64 ~/restproject
   $ node app
  { username: [ 'This field is required.' ],
  password: [ 'This field is required.' ] }
```

I am not sure how to pass username and password for authentication.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're mixing different HTTP libraries, because I don't believe node.js https library has a `data` property.

The internal library is fairly low-level, and not super easy to work with. I think you're reusing properties from other HTTP clients.

The built-in client requires you to actually build the body manually and send it over the socket. I'd suggest you use a higher level library instead. One that's a bit more tailored for the end-user case.

The [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library is a great library, because it implements the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) that also exists in browsers. If I were to rewrite your sample using that library, it looks more like this:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function getPrice() {

  const body = {
    username: "admin",
    password: "adminpw",
    tenant: "master"
  };

  const uri = 'https://10.41.74.70//tron/api/v1/tokens';
  const response = fetch(uri, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
     'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  });

  if (response.status > 400) {
    throw new Error('HTTP error: '  + response.status);
  }
  const price = await response.json();
  console.log(price);

}

getPrice();
```

I can't guarantee the above is correct though, because:

- I didn't test it
- I'm not 100% certain what the intent of your code is, I can only guess
- I don't know how your API works